# Python 3.6 Returning [ ] instead of entered value

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a script mentioned in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30389/industrial-handheld-qrcode-scanner-open-url-in-browser to take a URL from keyboard entry or a QR code scanner and automatically open it in a browser.

When I run this script in python 3.6, it's printing [] instead of the actual input. When I remove the re.findall it formats it correctly, but I'm not sure what part in the re.findall is causing the problem.

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import re
import webbrowser
endDomains = ".com|.net|.org|.edu|.gov|.mil|.aero|.asia|.biz|.cat|.coop|.info|.int|.jobs|.mobi|.museum|.name|.post|.pro|.tel|.travel".split("|")
chars = ""

def pressed_chars(event):
    global chars
    if event.Ascii:
        char = chr(event.Ascii)  
        if event.Ascii == 3:
            quit()
        else:
            chars += char
            try:
                urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', chars)
                print(urls)
            except:
                urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', chars)
                print(urls)
            if len(urls) > 0:
                for url in urls:
                    for i in endDomains:
                        if i in url:
                            webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                            chars = ""
                            break
    return 0

proc = pyHook.HookManager()
proc.KeyDown = pressed_chars
proc.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list.  If it returns an empty list `[]` then it didn't find any matches.  The test `if len(urls) > 0` suggests that this is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was a missing spacer so this

```
http[s]?://([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

should be

```
http[s]?://|([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```